# Convert FSCalendar into islamic Umm Al-qura calendar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I am trying to make Islamic/Hijri calendar using FSCalendar library in which months and date should show according to Islamic month and date. So far i have tried

```
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale
    let GregorianDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "13-07-2016")
    let islamic = NSCalendar.init(calendarIdentifier: .islamicUmmAlQura)
    let components = (islamic?.components(NSCalendar.Unit(rawValue: UInt.max), from: GregorianDate!))!
    let date = NSCalendar.current.date(from: components)!
    hijriCalendar.setCurrentPage(date, animated: true)
```

but no luck.
can i get some guide for this conversion

[image]

Comment: can you find any solution how to achieve this in our ios application swift uikit

Comment: I did not find any specific library for this purpose, so I used the FSCalendar library. In this library, I set hijriCalendar.calendarIdentifier = NSCalendar.Identifier.islamicUmmAlQura.rawValue, which converts the calendar into Hijri.

Comment: After you set the above line, it will convert the calendar into Hijri, but it does not show the correct current date. So, I used code like this: let today = Date() let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: +1, to: today) hijriCalendar.today = tomorrow."

Comment: ok thanks let me try

Comment: please upvote, if it helps.